# Why does my Canvas not draw the rectangles

Tags: java

I know this problem has probably already been solved before but I don't really know how to describe the problem well, so I have a hard time finding it.

The problem I have is that I have a canvas that is attached to a panel and that panel is attached to a main panel and that to the frame. When I run the code the canvas does nothing. However if I dont add the button panel it works.

this is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ColorFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final int FRAMEWIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAMEHEIGHT = 400;
    private int aORec = 4;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton lessButton;
    private JButton moreButton;

    public ColorFrame() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        panel = new JPanel();
        canvas = new painter();

        panel.add(canvas);
        mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        createComponents();
        add(mainPanel);

        setSize(FRAMEWIDTH,FRAMEHEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        lessButton = new JButton("Less");
        moreButton = new JButton("More");

        ActionListener bL = new ButtonListener();

        lessButton.addActionListener(bL);
        moreButton.addActionListener(bL);

        buttonPanel.add(moreButton);
        buttonPanel.add(lessButton);

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    class painter extends Canvas {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for (int i = 0; i < aORec; i++) {
                int tempWidth = (int)(Math.random() * (FRAMEWIDTH-0));
                int tempHeight = (int)(Math.random() * (FRAMEHEIGHT -0));
                g.drawRect(tempWidth,tempHeight,20,20);
            }
        }
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == moreButton) {
                aORec =+ aORec;
                canvas.repaint();
            } else {
                if (aORec != 1) {
                    aORec -= (aORec*0.5);
                    canvas.repaint();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("There are not enough rectangles to be drawn.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main panel is created by

```
mainPanel = new JPanel();
```

Components are being added to the main panel as

```
mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

but no `LayoutManager` was set, so the default `FlowLayout` is used, not `BorderLayout`. Create the panel by

```
mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

or add the statement

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

This is also valid for `panel` (otherwise it will not be resized, that is, stay with size zero)

<sup>(`BorderLayout` is the default for `JFrame`(</sup>

Comment: I did what you suggested however, it didn't work but when I did the same thing you suggested to the panel I added the canvas too, it seemed to work. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that is needed for both panels.... BTW: ` aORec =+ aORec;` is doing nothing, probably wanted to use `+=`

Comment: Edited answer to include second panel